# Fail: AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Container'

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I try to start `python-pptx`, but I have Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Container'
in File "...\lib\site-packages\pptx_init_.py", line 14
```

Use Python 3.10, python-pptx (0.6.21), lxmx (4.6.3).

Comment: Please include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 31):

It's a known issue for Python 3.10 as discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/762). The workaround is to import both modules `collections` and
`collections.abc` before importing `pptx`. For example:

```py
import collections 
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation
```

This should resolve this error

Comment: I am not seeing the collections in pypi.org. What is the pip install?