# TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xFill' Python deepcopy error

Tags: python, object, copy, deep-copy, python-pptx

I am trying to deep copy a Powerpoint object in Python. When I try to copy the presentation object to a new variable it gives an error. When doing a shallow copy it does not give any errors, so it has something to do with the deep copy.

**Expected output**

Makes a copy of the presentation object without errors.

```
from pptx import Presentation
import copy

prs1 = Presentation()
prs1.slide_width = Cm(75)
prs1.slide_height = Cm(45)
slide_layout = prs1.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs1.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
shapes = slide.shapes

prs2 = copy.deepcopy(prs)


TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xFill'
```

I know it has been asked before, but I don't get it. What do I have to add as argument? `__new__`?

This also gives a error: `prs2 = copy.deepcopy(prs, Presentation.__new__)`

Also a shallow copy does not work, because when I change something in the copied object the orginal object changes aswell.

Comment: The `prs` in `copy.deepcopy(prs)` is not defined in the code you've shown. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

change prs to prs1 in the below line because only prs1 is used in the code so far

```
prs2 = copy.deepcopy(prs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use python 3.10. There are no problem. 
 But somebody [already faced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70631361/17517937) problem with collections import:

```
import collections 
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation
```